# Where are the bounties at?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

Currently there is the lovely 'sort' feature for sorting through millions of questions. I am an SO user, but I guess other sites users could benefit from this feature. Please add the ability to sort questions down to bounties, by tags would be a plus, but for starters, just bounties. Right now we can 'Select A Sort' for :

- Active
- Votes
- Newest
- Hot
- Unanswered - Newest
- Unanswered - My tags

Where's the love guys! Where's the bounties! My tired little fingers can't take saving questions as favorites , when in any other world, extraterrestrial or otherwise, they would never be my favorite question! Just to answer it later or be able to see it. I need the 50+ notification in my top right navigation item!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.4.4.6, currently in review.

More details are at [Stack Exchange iOS app is getting new question nav](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276115/stack-exchange-ios-app-is-getting-new-question-nav) but you will now be able to save custom question list sorts including bounties on tags.

Comment: Love it! Thanks for the detailed response. Keep up the good work. If you need a beta tester let me know: soulshined@me.com I have apps in the store so can offer sound & sane feedback. Otherwise thanks for not forgetting lol. I totally forgot about this request, as I type in the iOS app.