# Restoring default sorting options in the iOS app?

Tags: support, ios-app, sorting

I've accidentally removed the default "With Bounty" sorting option from the Questions page of Ask Different. Is there any way to restore this default sort?

[image: the default sorting option "with bounty" has been accidentally deleted]

*the default sorting option "with bounty" has been accidentally deleted.*

Comment: What is "With Bounty" sort? You mean the featured tab? If so, just click it again.

Comment: Uh, let me add a screenshot

Comment: Oh, you mean the iOS app. Missed the tag. Still, screenshot is better and maybe mention you mean the app in the title.

Comment: Title has been edited and screenshots added.

Comment: Thanks, clearer now. Got android app so afraid I can't really help though. Good luck! :)

Comment: Probably related: [Stack Exchange iOS app is getting new question nav](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276115/stack-exchange-ios-app-is-getting-new-question-nav). Have you tried creating a new "view"? (I don't have iOS devices to test)

Comment: @bacon I will have a look at that. I'll add an answer if it solves my issue.